# Implementing listview adapter to accept all arguments

Tags: android, while-loop, adapter

Am so called newer to android development and i'm developing my first app, I was looking for a way to list content of the app and i found `listview`is one of the way i can show the content but i have to use custom adapter to style it. After looking around relevant questions how adapter is been made i found a good reference here [Custom Adapter for List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view) and my listview is able to work but the problem i am only seeing the last row of my while() contents.
This problem is because

> ThreeStrings threeStrings =  new ThreeStrings(feed_title, feed_date,
>   feed_radio); threeStringsList.add(threeStrings);

has been defined inside while loop as am new to java am not able to implement it to pass all the elements to adapter.

```
            List<ThreeStrings> threeStringsList = new ArrayList<>();
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.datalistview);
            ThreeHorizontalTextViewsAdapter threeHorizontalTextViewsAdapter = new ThreeHorizontalTextViewsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.three_horizontal_text_views_layout, threeStringsList);
            listView.setAdapter(threeHorizontalTextViewsAdapter);
            // fields of feed [array] and loop
            int feed_id;
            String feed_radio, feed_title, feed_api, feed_frequency, feed_type, feed_date;
            JSONObject feeds = object.getJSONObject("feeds");
            Iterator<String> keys = feeds.keys();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                JSONObject row = feeds.getJSONObject(keys.next());
                feed_title  = row.getString("feed_title");
                feed_radio  = row.getString("feed_radio");
                feed_date   = row.getString("feed_date");
                ThreeStrings threeStrings =  new ThreeStrings(feed_title, feed_date, feed_radio);
                threeStringsList.add(threeStrings);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

Is there anyone who can help to make it work?

**EDIT**

```
public class ThreeHorizontalTextViewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ThreeStrings> {

private int layoutResource;

public ThreeHorizontalTextViewsAdapter(Context context, int layoutResource, List<ThreeStrings> threeStringsList) {
    super(context, layoutResource, threeStringsList);
    this.layoutResource = layoutResource;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResource, null);
    }

    ThreeStrings threeStrings = getItem(position);

    if (threeStrings != null) {
        TextView leftTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.leftTextView);
        TextView rightTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rightTextView);
        TextView centreTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.centreTextView);

        if (leftTextView != null) {
            leftTextView.setText(threeStrings.getLeft());
        }

        if (rightTextView != null) {
            rightTextView.setText(threeStrings.getRight());
        }

        if (centreTextView != null) {
            centreTextView.setText(threeStrings.getCentre());
        }
    }

    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: What does your json look like - the adding threeStrings object to the list looks correct. So I'm wondering where the error is

Comment: show ThreeHorizontalTextViewsAdapter  class code?

Comment: The problem is not in the json the problem should be raisin from here ThreeStrings threeStrings = new ThreeStrings(feed_title, feed_date, feed_radio); threeStringsList.add(threeStrings); cos on every loop its becoming new object

Comment: @Makwana see it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view

Comment: @LazyLoading try to set adapter after while loop maybe that will hlep. But better solution is to use `AsyncTask<>` then populate adapter with data `onPostExecute()`

Comment: am trying the first suggestion the sec AsyncTask<> then populate adapter with data onPostExecute()  means i av to start looking around as am a beginner

Comment: @Yupi its not working

Comment: @Yupi if possible give me an example on what you suggest as an answer

Comment: @LazyLoading update your post with adapter code.

Comment: i Updated the code

Comment: @LazyLoading seems you don't have any errors inside adapter.

Comment: The adapter is able to display data without any problem but am only seeing one row which is also the last row of the loop

Comment: is it okay to define ThreeStrings threeStrings = new ThreeStrings(feed_title, feed_date, feed_radio); threeStringsList.add(threeStrings); while inside while()-loop? i was expecting this to be out the while()-loop but  threeStringsList.add(threeStrings); to support adding of three arguments while inside while(0-loop

Comment: @LazyLoading zip and upload your project on dropbox or google drive and share a link I'm little bit curious now why is not working.

Comment: The whole folder?

Comment: @Yupi am uploading the whole wait for me

Comment: @Yupi https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_DNKWfE9-7OZXJpOWJ2UXpxWlU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @LazyLoading okay let me check

Comment: The fetched example data is here `http://www.mobiledatabook.com/smsradio/voice/v1/radio/feeds.php` and `http://www.mobiledatabook.com/smsradio/voice/v1/radio/feeds.php?feeds_to_array=ok` it ll help you formatted php_array

Comment: @LazyLoading seems url in project doesn't work throws execption

Comment: if its not working just copy the test data http://www.mobiledatabook.com/smsradio/voice/v1/radio/feeds.‌​php its json and use localhost

Comment: i observe the error too but on localhost is working

Comment: Did it work? its too early here i have to take a bit least @2:25am